# Total user in a day and in a week

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to get the total number of users joined in a day and in a week, what I tried is as follows

```
member_in_day = User.objects.exclude(is_staff=True)\
    .annotate(day=TruncDay('date_joined')).values('date_joined') \
    .annotate(total_members=Count('date_joined')) \
    .order_by('-date_joined')
member_in_week = User.objects.exclude(is_staff=True)\
    .annotate(week=TruncWeek('date_joined')).values('date_joined') \
    .annotate(total_members=Count('date_joined')) \
    .order_by('-date_joined')
```

The model is user the output I am getting is same for both queries, instead of a day it is giving other queryset also. How I can get todays total and this week total to template

```
<QuerySet [{'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 28, 16, 47, 40, 509134, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}, {'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 23, 11, 8, 19, 241355, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}, {'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 23, 11, 6, 14, 20673, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}, {'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 22, 9, 25, 45, 14632, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}, {'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 22, 9, 24, 25, 819750, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}, {'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 20, 12, 7, 37, 59113, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}]> members
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `date_joined`, but `day` or `week` after you truncate, so:

```
member_in_day = User.objects.exclude(is_staff=True).values(
    day=TruncDay('date_joined')
).annotate(
    total_members=Count('date_joined')
).order_by('-day')
```

THe same with `members_in_week`:

```
member_in_week = User.objects.exclude(is_staff=True).values(
    week=TruncWeek('date_joined')
).annotate(
    total_members=Count('date_joined')
).order_by('-week')
```

Comment: @Biju: you *don't*: a template should *not* be concerned with business logic, only with *rendering* logic, you should do this in the view, and pass it to the template.

Comment: <QuerySet [{'week': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}, {'week': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 4}, {'week': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}]> Members

Comment: <QuerySet [{'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}, {'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 2}, {'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 22, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 2}, {'day': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total_members': 1}]> members

Comment: this is the present output

Comment: @Biju: you can iterate over the queryset, like `{% for item in myqs %}{{ item.week }}: {{item.total_members }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: Amazingly helpful, thank you